# Stacked canvas event

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, mouseevent

I have a canvas with a transparent background on top of another one and want mouse events to be registered by elements on both of them. However, the upper canvas prevents any mouse events reaching the lower one. What is the best approach?

```
     <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner" id="canvas_container_1"></div>  
      <div class="inner" id="canvas_container_2"></div>   
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is simulating a trigger on all elements like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AzNQb/.

```
var handler = function(e) {
    // the actual handler
    console.log(e.pageX, this);
};

$(".inner").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    var args = arguments;
    var value;
    $(".inner").each(function() {
        // call handler for each element; preserve `return false` functionality
        if(handler.apply(this, args) === false) {
            value = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return value;
});
```

Comment: However, I want the mouse events to be triggered properly at both canvases, not just calling a specific handler function. I tried using this.trigger(e) inside the .each function, but it did not work. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

on both, do you mean the 2 inner canvas ?

if yes = then just add an event listener on your "inner" class :

`$('.outer').on('click','.inner',function() { ... })`